# Calling spec_helper file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm new in rspec test. My spec directory contain various subfolders: controllers, models, views, requests, helpers(all helper file located here) etc. So if I want to call(require) `/helpers/crud_helper_spec.rb` from `/controllers/crud_contrller_spec.rb`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Any helpers you write you can put in `spec/support`, like your CRUD helper in `spec/support/crud_helper.rb`:

```
module CrudHelper
  # Fancy helpers here
end
```

Your `spec/spec_helper` is probably already configured to require these files. To use the helpers in a controller spec, do the following

```
describe PostsController do
  include CrudHelper

  it { fancy_helper(:index) }
end
```

Comment: I didn't see spec/spec_helper.rb in my project, so should I add this file as regular?

Comment: Yes, add it. Rspec itself uses one, and includes it in every spec file they create. See https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/tree/master/spec for details.